# TypeScript doesn't catch error with incorrect interface props when setting state - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Although I defined an interface with very specific props and set that interface to be used in useState, no error is caught when I set the value of this state to an array of objects with incompatible props:

Definition of ResultProps:

```
interface ResultProps {
    answer: string;
    count: number;
    id: string;
    incrementCount: incrementCount; // simple function that returns void
}
```

setting type of results to ResultProps[]:

```
  const [results, setResults] = useState<ResultProps[]>([]);
```

Then, when manipulating results and using setResults with incorrect props (**'count'** and **'incrementCount'** function are not included, **'randomProp'** is added), no error is reported -

```
    const resultsArr = results.map(
    (result: ResultProps, i: number) => {
      return {
        result: result,
        id: String(i),
        randomProp: 'random'
      };
    }
  );

  setResults(resultsArr); // no TS error caught
```

What could be causing TS to not detect this type mismatch?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[TS red underline error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwB3e.png)

Hi. TS is giving error on try the code provided by you. may be the issue is something else. below is the screenshot and the full code I used.

[full error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znIV5.png)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

interface ResultProps {
    answer: string;
    count: number;
    id: string;
    incrementCount: () => void; // simple function that returns void
}

const Sample : React.FC= () => {
    const [results, setResults] = useState<ResultProps[]>([]);

    const resultsArr = results.map(
        (result: ResultProps, i: number) => {
          return {
            result: result,
            id: String(i),
            randomProp: 'random'
          };
        }
      );
    
      setResults(resultsArr)
    return(
        <>
        <h2>Sample App</h2>
        </>
    )
}

export default Sample;
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. 
It looks the issue is coming from another line of code, where I destructure JSON data I retrieve from a data attribute:

                   const data = domElement.getAttribute("data-results");
                   const { results } = JSON.parse(data);

After that, the mapping of 'results' doesn't cause an error, but if I remove it - the TS error occurs. Still not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue is with JSON.parse

When we use JSON.parse it returns type any and typescript compiler won't trigger compile error when we supply any where function expects particular type.

Here, what you can do is either parse result like below

```
const resultAny = JSON.parse(data);

const result = <ResultProps[]>resultAny;
```

Or parsing is returning array then use map's generic feature to typecast what map is returning.

[Snippet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3ioK.jpg)